# Angular js - Using UI Bootstrap's Tab library only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using only the Tab component of UI Bootstrap.

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/tabs

After including the above library and adding following code resulted nothing in the browser. There is no errors in console either.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap.tabs']);

 <tabset justified="true">
    <tab heading="Justified">Justified content</tab>
    <tab heading="SJ">Short Labeled Justified content</tab>
    <tab heading="Long Justified">Long Labeled Justified content</tab>
  </tabset>
```

I've managed to get this work with full UI-Bootstrap library with same above code. I don't want to include the entire library as I'm using only the Tab module.

http://plnkr.co/edit/DCNry4vEcL2VrcP9lv9J?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the templates.  @Fieldset has the right idea, just maybe not the clearest recommendation for solving the issue.

### [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eGG2wwNthwJY3xD7GD2t?p=preview)

If you are only including the tabs.js, make sure to add the templates separately.  You can do this easily using the $templateCache script tags approach:

```
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="template/tabs/tabset.html">
      <div>
        <ul class="nav nav-{{type || 'tabs'}}" ng-class="{'nav-stacked': vertical, 'nav-justified': justified}" ng-transclude></ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane" 
               ng-repeat="tab in tabs" 
               ng-class="{active: tab.active}"
               tab-content-transclude="tab">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="template/tabs/tab.html">
      <li ng-class="{active: active, disabled: disabled}">
        <a href ng-click="select()" tab-heading-transclude>{{heading}}</a>
      </li>
    </script>
```